# 'dotnet nuget push ...' doesn't seem to be pushing the symbols

Tags: .net, nuget, package, push, symbols

```
dotnet clean --configuration Debug
dotnet build --configuration Debug --version-suffix beta.12
dotnet pack --include-symbols --include-source --configuration Debug --version-suffix beta.12
```

So far so good - the above three commands produce two nice packages: xyz.2.1.2-beta.12.nupkg and xyz.2.1.2-beta.12.symbols.nupkg. But when I run the last command:

```
dotnet nuget push bin\Debug\ --source https://www.nuget.org
```

fails with these messages:

> info : Pushing xyz.2.1.2-beta.12.nupkg to the NuGet gallery (https://www.nuget.org)...
>
> info :   PUT https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/
>
> warn : This package will only be available to download with SemVer 2.0.0 compatible NuGet clients,such as Visual Studio 2017 (version 15.3) and above or NuGet client 4.3 and above. For more information,see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=852248.
>
> info :   Created https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/ 1573ms
>
> info : Your package was pushed.
>
> info : Pushing xyz.2.1.2-beta.12.symbols.nupkg to the NuGet gallery (https://www.nuget.org)...
>
> info :   PUT https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/
>
> info :   Conflict https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/ 1006ms
>   error: Response status code does not indicate success: 409 (A package with ID 'xyz' and version '2.1.2-beta.12' already exists and cannot be modified.).

So, it is obvious that pushing of the symbol package fails. This is happening with both `dotnet nuget push...` or  `nuget push...`
What seems to be the problem?

Comment: According to the error message "A package with ID 'xyz' and version '2.1.2-beta.12' already exists and cannot be modified.)", it seems you are pushing the symbols package to the nuget.org, you should push it to the `https://nuget.smbsrc.net/` check the document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/symbol-packages

Comment: According to the doc this command is supposed to push both the normal package to  https://www.nuget.org and the symbols package (if found) to https://nuget.smbsrc.net. Even specifying -source AND -SymbolSource doesn't help. Tried all kinds of command lines and options - nothing works...

Comment: @Valo, Any luck with this?

Comment: @Fabio Milheiro, honestly don't remember anymore - sorry!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've just had this issue and fixed it few minutes ago.

There is a new format for Symbols package which is `.snupkg` extension.

If you're using `dotnet cli` or `nuget cli` you can do the following:

**Pack:**

DOTNET CLI

```sh
dotnet pack MyAwesomeLib.csproj --include-symbols -p:SymbolPackageFormat=snupkg -c release
```

NUGET CLI

```sh
nuget pack MyAwesomeLib.nuspec -Symbols -SymbolPackageFormat snupkg
```

**Publish:**

DOTNET CLI

```sh
 dotnet nuget push MyAwesomeLib.1.0.0.nupkg -s https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json -k ~~your API key here~~
```

NUGET CLI

```sh
nuget push MyAwesomeLib.1.0.1.nupkg -Source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json -apikey ~~your API key here~~
```

You can read more about this from [here](https://blog.nuget.org/20181116/Improved-debugging-experience-with-the-NuGet-org-symbol-server-and-snupkg.html).

Comment: This is exactly what I'm doing and it does not seem to publish the snupkg at all.